# If $R$ is a strict partial order prove that is asymmetric

Tags: relations, order-theory

Suppose $R$ is a relation on a set $A$, and $R$ is asymmetric if:

$\forall x \in A$ $\forall y \in A$ $((x, y) \in R \rightarrow (y, x)\not \in R)$

The first point of the exercise was to demonstrate that if $R$ is *asymmetric* then it is also *antisymmetric*.

What I am not understanding is a proof solution to the following question:

> Show that if $R$ is a *strict partial order*, then it is also
>   *asymmetric*.

A partial order is a binary relation on a set, say, $A$ that is *reflexive*, *antisymmetric* and *transitive*.

And the proof is the following:

> Suppose that R is a strict partial order, and suppose that for some
>   $x,y \in A$, $(x,y) \in R$ and $(y,x) \in R$. Then by transitivity of
>   $R$, $(x, x) \in R$, which contradicts the fact that $R$ is
>   irreflexive. Therefore, $R$ is asymmetric.

What exactly I am not understanding is why if $(x,y) \in R$ and $(y,x) \in R$, since $R$ is antisymmetric. At least, $x = y$. Then I also cannot understand why it follows immediately that it's *asymmetric*.

Comment: These notions arise naturally in different contexts. When presented in the abstract they may seem like meaningless bean counting, but they are useful tools for categorizing relations.

Answer (score 1):

A *strict partial order* is a relation $R$ that is *irreflexive* (for every $x\in A$, $(x,x)\notin R$) and transitive.

Why is it *asymmetric*? Suppose $(x,y)\in R$ and $(y,x)\in R$; by transitivity, $(x,x)\in R$, which isn't true because the relation is irreflexive.

Therefore, if $(x,y)\in R$, it holds that $(y,x)\notin R$.

---

Why did mathematicians invented all that? Simple: strict partial orders and (lax) partial orders are exactly the same thing.

If $A$ is a set, write $\Delta(A)=\{(x,x):x\in A\}$.

If $S$ is a strict partial order on $A$, then $S^*=S\cup\Delta(A)$ is a partial order on $A$ (prove it).

If $R$ is a partial order on $A$, then $R_*=R\setminus\Delta(A)$ is a strict partial order on $A$ (prove it).

Note also that $(S^*)_*=S$ and $(R_*)^*=R$, so there is a very well behaved bijection between the strict and the lax partial order relations on $A$.

Think to the above as the connection between $<$ and $\le$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help, but let's try it out.

For every $x\in R$ and $y\in R$, there are only four possibilities:

- $(x,y)\in R$ and $(y,x)\in R$
- $(x,y)\notin R$ but $(y,x)\in R$
- $(x,y)\in R$ but $(y,x)\notin R$, or
- $(x,y)\notin R$ and $(y,x)\notin R$.

A reflection is asymmetric if only the last three ever occur. The proof shows that it is impossible for the first to occur in $R$, and therefore we conclude that $R$ is asymmetric.